# Import python package from terminal

Tags: python, terminal, package

I want to run a Python script in my terminal (mac) that takes a csv file as input. At the beginning of the Pyton script, a package named cvxpy is imported. When running the code with data in the terminal I get the error:

ImportError: No module named cvxpy.

I'm feeling it's a directory fault, but I don't know how to fix this (e.g. how to get the Python script and python packaga in the same directory)

Somebody got a clue?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the module installed.
To install it, type : `pip3 install cvxpy`
If you already have it installed, please double check by typing `pip3 list`

Comment: This is the part which I don't get, this package is installed and well. Any idea why it's still giving me this error?

Comment: can you type `python` then `import cvxpy` in your terminal ?

Comment: you got me there, when I do this indeed it gives me the same error. I get the "ImportError: no module names cvxpy". So to summarize: in PyCharm the package is installed, but the terminal doesn't recognize this fact. This is why I thought maybe about a directory fault?

Comment: I think that you have multiple versions of python installed, the one you're using in pycharm isn't in your PATH environment variable and so you must have installed the module in this version. Fix it by either removing non useful python versions or by adding the one used by pycharm to PATH.

Comment: Thank! Simply running it with "python3" instead of python seemed to call the right version of python.